# Tcl : pkg_mkIndex works with directory, but not with filename

Tags: tcl

Here is a transscript from my session (Tcl 8.5 on OSX 10.6.8):

```
$ tclsh
% ls
aux.tcl     myapp       myprj.tcl   oshiri      prjmain.tcl
% pkg_mkIndex aux.tcl
no files matched glob patterns "*.tcl *.dylib"
% pkg_mkIndex .
% ls
aux.tcl     myprj.tcl   pkgIndex.tcl
myapp       oshiri      prjmain.tcl
% exit
```

Why can't I supply an individual filename for the pkg_mkIndex command? From the example given at http://wiki.tcl.tk/3388, I had concluded that it should be possible.

BTW, the form

```
% pkg_mkIndex *.tcl
```

doesn't work either (same error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command syntax demands that the arguments be 1) options, 2) **a directory**, 3) patterns to search for within that directory (with `*.tcl` and the pattern for shared libraries on your platform as default patterns).

You should be able to do

```
pkg_mkIndex . aux.tcl
```

indexing just this one file.

The error message is telling you that the command can't find any Tcl files or shared libraries inside the file aux.tcl, which tells us that the implementation of `pkg_mkIndex` doesn't check if the directory given actually *is* a directory. As I said in an earlier answer, it's somewhat naïve, bless its heart.

Documentation: [pkg_mkIndex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/pkgMkIndex.htm)